# Variance of infinite sum.

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

We have a sequence $(X_n)$ of independent real valued random variables with $EX_n=0$ and $EX_n^2<\infty$. I know that $X_n \to 0$ in $L^2$ and $X_n \to 0$ a.s.

If we define $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$, I have proved that $S_n$ converges almost surely to some limit for $n\to \infty$.

If we let $S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ denote the almost sure limit of $S_n$, I want to show that S has finite variance and compute the variance.

Can someone help me get started?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\sum_k \text{Var}(X_k) <\infty$ then $(S_n)$ is Cauchy in $L^2$, and therefore converge to some limit in $L^2$ (by completeness of $L^2$). By uniqueness of limits we have that $S_n \to S$ almost surely and $\|S_n-S\|_2 \to_n 0$. $L^2$ convergence implies $L^1$ convergence hence by the triangle inequality for integrals we have that
$$
|ES_n-ES|\leq E|S_n - S|  \to_n 0,
$$
proving that $E(S)=\lim_{n\to \infty} E(S_n)=0$. We have that $S$ is an element of $L^2$, and therefore we know that the variance exists (is finite) and is given by
$$
\text{Var}(S)=E((S-E(S))^2) = E(S^2)=\lim_{n\to \infty} E(S_n^2) =\lim_{n\to \infty} \text{Var}(S_n)
$$
$$ = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \text{Var}(X_k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \text{Var}(X_k),
$$
where we also used the reverse triangle inequality to say that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} | \|S_n\|_2-\|S\|_2| \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}  \|S_n-S\|_2 =0 \implies E(S_n^2)\to_n E(S^2)
$$

Comment: Thank you, it was a great help!